# Adding a custom base class for my asp.net page yields error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a custom derived page, rather than System.Web.UI.Page as the base for my web pages, however Visual Studio 2012 (ASP.Net) refuses to recognize the new base class.  The code appears sound, just VS does not recognize the new base class.

1. I created a folder off of the project root called, App_Code
2. Into that folder I added a new ASP.net class called SitePage.cs
3. Into the SitePage.cs, here is the content

   ```
   using System;  
   using System.Collections.Generic;  
   using System.Linq;  
   using System.Web;  
   using System.Web.UI;  

    public class SitePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {  
         protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)  
            {  
                  base.OnPreInit(e);  
          }  

   public SitePage()  
   {  
   }
   ```

   }
4. On the code behind for a webpage, say Default.aspx.cs, I tried replacing

   public partial class Default : Page

with

```
public partial class Default : SitePage
```

The problem is that SitePage gets a squiggly red line.  SitePage does not appear in the dropdown of choices, no clue why, and yields the error, "The type or namespace name 'SitePage' cound not be found."

I am using ASP.Net v4.0 (non MVC) with Visual Studio.  I created a brand new project to test/work with this issue, so no underlying baggage.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is SitePage in the same namespace as Default.aspx.cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include it as a reference (look for the "references" option in solution explorer) before Default.aspx.cs will know what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. There is no option "references", but the solution was to change "Build Action" from "Content" to "Compile".  Thanks for getting me past that.  This problem was not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the custom base class, but **before** you change the base class from your page, you need to build the project.

So, for now what you have to do is:

- Make sure `Default` inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page`
- Build your project
- Reapply `SitePage` as the base class for `Default`

Comment: I built the project multiple times after that.  True, I might need to build the project twice after a clean, but the immediate problem, and for me not obvious, is that I had to change the build action from "Content", which is the default given by Visual Studio, to "Compile".  I thought all C# CS pages are compiled.  I have tons of class CS pages, which compile nicely.  I do not follow the difference.  Thoughts anyone?